# How can I replace an image using only a CSS Stylesheet

Tags: html, css, inline

I was wondering if it was possible to replace an image on an html page using the only the stylesheet. I know this is not common practice, but the only thing I have access to is the stylesheet and they used inline styles in the html. I have no way of editing the html file.

I inspected the element and it looks like this:

I'm trying to replace the "bullet_ball_glass_green" image. I was able to hide it by adding this to the stylesheet:

```
.rmLeftImage{

visibility: hidden;
}
```

But is it possible to replace the image or add another one on top of it without editing the html page?

Comment: Is the html element an <img> or not?

Comment: Look into the the ::before pseudo element and set the new image as the background-image of that ::before element. You'll probably need to take off visibility hidden though and this wouldnt work in old browsers

Comment: Yes it's an <img> sorry, not sure why the code didn't post. The html looks like this: <img alt="" src="/MemberToolsDotNet/(S(a3bhwjzute2ew4zyk0m0qk03))/art/bullet_ball_glass_green.gif" class="rmLeftImage">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the background image of a div around the image (and keeping the css you have that hides the image).

```
.div_class{ 
  background:url('http://yourdomain.com/yourimage.jpg') no-repeat 50% 50%; 
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the css have a higher hierarchy than the style in html, you could just add

```
img.rmLeftImage {
   background-image: url('path to your image');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep hiding the image with

> visibility:hidden;

since you want it to keep the width/height of the image and change the background image with

> background:url('urltoyourimage')

Answer (score 0):

Here is, perhaps a slightly controversial technique with support on [IE8+ and pretty much every other browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=after).

```
.rmLeftImage { 
    content: '';
}

.rmLeftImage:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    background: url(../your/new/image);
    width: 220px; /* image width */
    height: 240px; /* image height */
    position: relative;  /* image width */
}
​
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/z9QUu/2/ for an example. I've only tested this in chrome so far, where it appears to work. Providing it works cross-browser, you won't need to modify the HTML, at all.

Interestingly, I could only get it to work when applying `content: '';` to `.rmLeftImage`, heres the jsfiddle without it: http://jsfiddle.net/Mw76h/, just for demonstration purposes.